# Replace string using Regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, string

```
text = "The%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Park"
text = "The%20Park"
```

Even text has one `%20` or multiple, it should have single char `'-'`  eg `The-Park`

```
var regex = new Regex("%20(%20)?");
var output = regex.Replace("The%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Park", "-");
output = The----Park
```

but output should be `The-Park`

Comment: `"%20(%20)?"` -> `"%20(%20)*"` -> `"(%20)+"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, thanks its worked fine.

Comment: I added an answer with explanations and an alternative non-regex solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pretty close - use `(%20)+` expression to match one or more occurrences of `%20`:

```
var regex = new Regex("(%20)+");
var output = regex.Replace("The%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Park", "-");
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/YqB2nL)

Good chances are, regex alone is not the right tool for the job. The string looks URL-encoded, with `%20` representing spaces. You may be better off URL-decoding your string prior to applying a regex that looks for whitespace.

Comment: thanks and its my first regex build. Its URL-encoded. i need to `-` instead of space so that i used regex.

Comment: @sagivasan I would decode, replace, and re-encode just to be safe.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex `%20(%20)?` matches a `%20` and then 1 or 0 (an optional) `%20` substring.

To match zero or more, you need to use `*` quantifier - `%20(%20)*`. However, this is equal to `(%20)+` since `+` matches 1 or more occurrences of the quantified subpattern.

You can also use a non-regex approach with split and join.

See [C# demo](https://ideone.com/hgQDhw)

```
var s = "The%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Park";
var regex = new Regex("(%20)+", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
var output = regex.Replace(s, "-");
Console.WriteLine(output);           // => The-Park

output  = string.Join("-", s.Split(new[] {"%20"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
Console.WriteLine(output);           // => The-Park
```

Note that it is a good idea to use `RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture` if you do not want capturing groups (pairs of unescaped `(...)`) in your pattern to create a stack for keeping captured values (just to steamline matching a bit).

Answer (score 1):

I think you got your RegEx wrong.

The `Regex.Replace()` function is a greedy function that will always try to find the biggest string corresponding to your RegEx.

Your RegEx is `%20(%20)?` Which means "One occurrence of `%20` plus zero or one occurrence of  `%20`" As you can see you find 4 of them in your string.

The RegEx you should be using is `(%20)+` Which means "One or more occurrence of `%20`"